# is it important the order of the namespace in the root? is possible to order them?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have the original xml that has the following struct:

```
<Root xmlns="http://xyz.com/2006/root" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xyz.com/2006/root.xsd">
```

To create a new xml, I use this code:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://xyz.com/2006/root";
            XNamespace xsiNs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
                new XElement(ns + "root",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsiNs),
                    new XAttribute(xsiNs + "schemaLocation",
                        "http://xyz.com/2006/root.xsd"),
            ));
```

The result is:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xyz.com/2006/root.xsd" xmlns="http://xyz.com/2006/root">
```

How we can see, in the original the xmls is the first attribute, xmls:xsi is the second and the xsi:schemalocation is the last one. In the new xml the order is different.

I would like know if the order is impotant or not.

However, to learn more about xml, I would like to know if there is any way to order the attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of attributes (including namespace declaration attributes) in XML has no significance. XML processing tools are not required to retain the original order.

Comment: +1 and for more details here is [Reference - Section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags)